# Resize parent widget when child widget is manually resized

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside6, pyqt6

I am working on a resizable widget in Qt.
This is a custom widget that should be able to be resized by the user when they hover and drag over its edges. Problem is, when resized, the parent widget's size and layout stays the same, although the resizable widget is originally placed in an HBoxLayout of the parent widget.
[image: See this gif]

I still can't find any info that works as intended.
I have tried `layout.update()` but that only snaps the resizable widget (green) to the size of the parent window.

`parent.adjustSize()` reduces the size of the parent and its child widgets to the smallest possible size

`widget.adjustSize()` does nothing on the resized widget

For now, the resizable widget class works fine as a resizable frameless window.
But suppose this widget was a child of another widget as shown in the image, would I need to manually reset the parent's size? Or are there any other available options?
All ideas appreciated.

Comment: A child should never directly try to alter properties of its parent. This is also valid for geometries. If that green widget is the only one visible for that window, you should use [QSizeGrip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html).

Comment: You're right @musicamante. I've resorted to using the resizable widget as the top level window instead.